# Voltage detected in off position of SPDT Switch

Tags: pcb-design, switches, circuit-design

I have an [ALPS Electric SSSS810701 SPDT switch](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Toggle-Switches_ALPS-Electric-SSSS810701_C97433.html) which I am using to control power to my PCB.

In the "switch on" position, I get 5 V as expected. But in the "switch off" position, I get 1.7 V instead of a value closer to zero

[image: part of schematic]

1. Output to PCB
2. Connected to 5 V
3. Floating

[image: part of schematic]

How do I fix this issue, please? Do I need to make a connection to ground across a resistor at position 1?

Comment: It might come from the PCB circuit, typ. any capacitors right at the input. You generally don't have to discharge them as they gradually discharge over time. If you leave the circuit in OFF for a minute or so after being on, do you observe a gradual voltage drop?

Comment: What is connected to VOUT?  Any voltage sources or charged capacitors there?

Comment: VOUT goes to my voltage regulator that regulates lipo battery volatage to 3.3v

Comment: @ched Before testing, make sure your output cap is discharged and shorted with a jumper while testing. Just to see if that's the source. Regardless, you could provide a pull-down on VOUT -- say 10 k? Then measure. I'd be curious about the results of both experiments.

Comment: The PCB is already printed. Luckily I am making a new version of the PCB to incoorporate a new feature. What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: @ched and your measuring from what point to what point with the mulitmeter?

Comment: I am measuring between vout and gnd

Comment: So does it gradually drop or is it constant? It would also help if you reported back on the proposed test by @jonk

Comment: The voltage is constant, it remains at 1.79v

Answer (score 0):

You probably have ionic contamination on your PCB. If this is causing issues, it can be avoided by specifying a different flux and cleaning process in your assembly.